# Username mapping, want to choose the backup server when primary server is down

Tags: windows-server-2003

Struggle with a batch-netlogon script for choosing the correct server when the main is down for maintance.

This is a part from the script:

```
:common
IF EXIST "\\topnet\users\%username%\." goto :topnet else :topserv
:topnet
net use U: \\topnet\Users\%USERNAME%
net time \\topprimo /Set /Yes
goto end
:topserv
net use U: \\topserv\Users\%USERNAME%
net time \\topprimo /Set /Yes
goto end
```

If the `\\topnet` server is offline the script must detect that, so it will be connected to the `\\topserv`

`topnet` is a domain controller 2003 and `topserv` is a BackupNAS.

The user maps are live synchronized from `topnet` -> `topserv`.

Comment: Have you thought about installing another domain controller instead of hosting backup copies of your logon scripts on a NAS?

Comment: 1. Why don't you use DFS for this? 2. You don't need to manually sync the time using the Net Time command. Domain joined clients will automatically sync their time with their authenticating DC. 3. Why are you syncing the time to topprimo? Is topprimo a DC? If not, you shouldn't be syncing domain joined clients to it.

Comment: DFS. No need to know a server name client side, the rest happens automatically.